# How can I create a 3d texture with negative values and read it from a shader

Tags: opengl, byte, textures, shader, jogl

I have written a volume rendering program that turns some 2d images into a 3d volume that can be rotated around by a user. I need to calculate a normal for each point in the 3d texture (for lighting) by taking the gradient in each direction around the point.

Calculating the normal requires six extra texture accesses within the fragment shader. The program is much faster without these extra texture access, so I am trying to precompute the gradients for each direction (x,y,z) in bytes and store it in the BGA channels of the original texture. My bytes seem to contain the right values when I test on the CPU, but when I get to the shader it comes out looking wrong. It's hard to tell why it fails from the shader, I think it is because some of the gradient values are negative. However, when I specify the texture type as GL_BYTE (as opposed to GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE) it is still wrong, and that screws up how the original texture should look. I can't tell exactly what's going wrong just by rendering the data as colors. What is the right way to put negative values into a texture? How can I know that values are negative when I read from it in the fragment shader?

The following code shows how I run the operation to compute the gradients from a byte array (byte[] all) and then turn it into a byte buffer (byteBuffer bb) that is read in as a 3d texture. The function 'toLoc(x,y,z,w,h,l)' simply returns (x+w*(y+z*h))*4)--it converts 3d subscripts to a 1d index. The image is grayscale, so I discard gba and only use the r channel to hold the original value. The remaining channels (gba) store the gradient.

```
        int pixelDiffxy=5;
    int pixelDiffz=1;

    int count=0;  
    Float r=0f;
    byte t=r.byteValue();

    for(int i=0;i<w;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<h;j++){
            for(int k=0;k<l;k++){
                count+=4;
                if(i<pixelDiffxy || i>=w-pixelDiffxy || j<pixelDiffxy || j>=h-pixelDiffxy || k<pixelDiffz || k>=l-pixelDiffz){
                    //set these all to zero since they are out of bounds
                    all[toLoc(i,j,k,w,h,l)+1]=t;//green=0
                    all[toLoc(i,j,k,w,h,l)+2]=t;//blue=0
                    all[toLoc(i,j,k,w,h,l)+3]=t;//alpha=0
                }
                else{

                    int ri=(int)all[toLoc(i,j,k,w,h,l)+0] & 0xff;

                    //find the values on the sides of this pixel in each direction (use red channel)
                    int xgrad1=(all[toLoc(i-pixelDiffxy,j,k,w,h,l)])& 0xff;
                    int xgrad2=(all[toLoc(i+pixelDiffxy,j,k,w,h,l)])& 0xff;

                    int ygrad1=(all[toLoc(i,j-pixelDiffxy,k,w,h,l)])& 0xff;
                    int ygrad2=(all[toLoc(i,j+pixelDiffxy,k,w,h,l)])& 0xff;

                    int zgrad1=(all[toLoc(i,j,k-pixelDiffz,w,h,l)])& 0xff;
                    int zgrad2=(all[toLoc(i,j,k+pixelDiffz,w,h,l)])& 0xff;


                    //find the difference between the values on each side and divide by the distance between them
                    int xgrad=(xgrad1-xgrad2)/(2*pixelDiffxy);
                    int ygrad=(ygrad1-ygrad2)/(2*pixelDiffxy);
                    int zgrad=(zgrad1-zgrad2)/(2*pixelDiffz);

                    Vec3f grad=new Vec3f(xgrad,ygrad,zgrad);

                    Integer xg=(int) (grad.x);
                    Integer yg=(int) (grad.y);
                    Integer zg=(int) (grad.z);

                    //System.out.println("gs are: "+xg +", "+yg+", "+zg);

                    byte gby= (byte) (xg.byteValue());//green channel
                    byte bby= (byte) (yg.byteValue());//blue channel
                    byte aby= (byte) (zg.byteValue());//alpha channel

                    //System.out.println("gba is: "+(int)gby +", "+(int)bby+", "+(int)aby);
                    all[toLoc(i,j,k,w,h,l)+1]=gby;//green
                    all[toLoc(i,j,k,w,h,l)+2]=bby;//blue
                    all[toLoc(i,j,k,w,h,l)+3]=aby;//alpha
                }
            }
        }
    }

ByteBuffer bb=ByteBuffer.wrap(all);
    final GL gl = drawable.getGL();
    final GL2 gl2 = gl.getGL2();
    final int[] bindLocation = new int[1];
    gl.glGenTextures(1, bindLocation, 0);
    gl2.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, bindLocation[0]);
    gl2.glPixelStorei(GL.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);//-byte alignment
    gl2.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL2.GL_CLAMP);
    gl2.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL2.GL_CLAMP);
    gl2.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL2.GL_CLAMP);
    gl2.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
    gl2.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
    gl2.glTexEnvf(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL.GL_REPLACE);
    gl2.glTexImage3D( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0,GL.GL_RGBA,
            w, h, l, 0,
            GL.GL_RGBA, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb );//GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE
```

Is there a better way to get a large array of signed data into the shader?

Comment: Are you using *shaders*, or glTexEnv? Because your code seems to contain the latter.

Comment: @NicolBolas I was originally using texenv but am using shaders now. I forgot to delete the line, but I'll get rid of it--doesn't change the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
gl2.glTexImage3D( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0,GL.GL_RGBA,
        w, h, l, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb );
```

Well, there are two ways to go about doing this, depending on how much work you want to do in the shader vs. what OpenGL version you want to limit things to.

The version that requires more shader work also requires a bit more out of your code. See, what you want to do is have your shader take unsigned bytes, then reinterpret them as signed bytes.

The way that this would typically be done is to pass unsigned normalized bytes (as you're doing), which produces floating-point values on the [0, 1] range, then simply expand that range by multiplying by 2 and subtracting 1, yielding numbers on the [-1, 1] range. This means that your uploading code needs to take it's [-128, 127] signed bytes and convert them into [0, 255] unsigned bytes by adding 128 to them.

I have no idea how to do this in *Java*, which does not appear to have an unsigned byte type at all. You can't just pass a 2's complement byte and expect it to work in the shader; that's not going to happen. The byte value -128 would map to the floating-point value 1, which isn't helpful.

If you can manage to convert the data properly as I described above, then your shader access would have to unpack from the [0, 1] range to the [-1, 1] range.

If you have access to GL 3.x, then you can do this quite easily, with no shader changes:

```
gl2.glTexImage3D( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0,GL.GL_RGBA8_SNORM,
        w, h, l, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, GL.GL_BYTE, bb );
```

The `_SNORM` in the image format means that it is a signed, normalized format. So your bytes on the range [-128, 127] will be mapped to floats on the range [-1, 1]. Exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried out the second option and it made a great difference!